# Vue Router , set to open external link... was working, now it's not...where should I look to figure out what i changed?

Tags: visual-studio, vue.js, vue-router

I have several routes set up like this in router/index.ts, so it'll open a new window to a external link

```
  {
        name: "0365Direct2",
        path: 'https://portal.office.com',
        beforeEnter() {
            window.open('https://portal.office.com',
                '_blank');
        }
    }
```

and linked like this in App.vue

```
 <router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 to="/0365Direct">0365 Direct</router-link> |
```

it was working, no idea what i changed to break it...  any idea where to look?

When I click the links, I jsut get a blank page.

The manual anchor tag works, but doesn't get formatted correctly. Which is why I moved to router links.

EDIT: I tried dropping and alert into one of the beforeEnter() functions, and
it appears it's never getting called. That's gotta be a hint, but for what..

EDIT2: If I wait it out, eventually it gives this error
This site can’t be reachedo365direct2 took too long to respond.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

---

Full files
:
Router\index.ts

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

import Auth from '@okta/okta-vue';

// our imports 
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import StudentPortalData from "../views/StudentPortalData.vue";
import StudentPasswordSet from "../views/StudentPasswordSet.vue";
import GetStudentInfo from "../views/GetStudentInfo.vue";
import GetStudentInfoSingleFile from "../views/GetStudentInfoSingleFile.vue";
import StudentPortalDlSched from "../views/StudentPortalDlSched.vue";
import StudentPortalDlSchedTS from "../views/StudentPortalDlSchedTS.vue";

// using JCDCs account (Tennant), Eric Dev apps SPA - EWB
//*
Vue.use(Auth,
    {
        issuer: 'https://dev-236765.okta.com/oauth2/default',
        client_id: '0oa169smwlhwTCyC14x7',
//        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080/implicit/callback',
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080/callback',
                        scope: 'openid profile email'
    });
//*/
/*
Vue.use(Auth, // Staff Prod
    {
        issuer: 'https://webauth.jobcorps.org/oauth2/default',
        client_id: '0oa512tkwwgEyw3oD357',
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080/implicit/callback',
        scope: 'openid profile email'
    });
//*/

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: '/implicit/callback',
        component: Auth.handleCallback()
    },
    {
        path: '/callback',
        component: Auth.handleCallback()
    },
    {
        path: '/StudentPortalData',
        name: 'StudentPortalData',
        component: StudentPortalData,
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true // requires okta auth - EWB
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/StudentPasswordSet',
        name: 'StudentPasswordSet',
        component: StudentPasswordSet,
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true // requires okta auth - EWB
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/GetStudentInfo',
        name: 'GetStudentInfo',
        component: GetStudentInfo,
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true // requires okta auth - EWB
        }
    },

    {
        path: '/GetStudentInfoSingleFile',
        name: 'GetStudentInfoSingleFile',
        component: GetStudentInfoSingleFile,
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true // requires okta auth - EWB
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/StudentPortalDlSched',
        name: 'StudentPortalDlSched',
        component: StudentPortalDlSched,
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true // requires okta auth - EWB
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/StudentPortalDlSchedTS',
        name: 'StudentPortalDlSchedTS',
        component: StudentPortalDlSchedTS,
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true // requires okta auth - EWB
        }
    },
    {
        name: "Calendar",
        path: "https://dev-236765.okta.com/home/google/0oa3mblbqpfFuNHjx357/54",
        beforeEnter() {
            window.open("https://dev-236765.okta.com/home/google/0oa3mblbqpfFuNHjx357/54",
                '_blank');
        }
    },
    {
        name: "GMail",
        path: "https://dev-236765.okta.com/home/google/0oa3mblbqpfFuNHjx357/50",
        beforeEnter() {
            window.open("https://dev-236765.okta.com/home/google/0oa3mblbqpfFuNHjx357/50",
                '_blank');
        } 
    },
    {
        name: "Classroom",
        path: "https://classroom.google.com",
        beforeEnter() {
            window.open("https://classroom.google.com",
                '_blank');
        }
    },
    {
        name: "0365",
        path: "https://dev-236765.okta.com/home/office365/0oa164ehoco8kRUHL4x7/30781",
        beforeEnter() {
            window.open("https://dev-236765.okta.com/home/office365/0oa164ehoco8kRUHL4x7/30781",
                '_blank');
        }
    },
    {
        name: "0365Direct2",
        path: 'https://portal.office.com',
        beforeEnter() {
            window.open('https://portal.office.com',
                '_blank');
        }
    }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes: routes
});

router.beforeEach(Vue.prototype.$auth.authRedirectGuard());

export default router;
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div><!--id-"app"-->
        <v-app>
            <v-app-bar app>
                <router-link class="pa-2" to="/">Home</router-link> |
                <!--<router-link class="pa-2" to="/about">About</router-link> |-->
                <router-link class="pa-2" to="/StudentPasswordSet">StudentPasswordSet</router-link> |
                <router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 to="/StudentPortalData">StudentPortalData</router-link> |
                <router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 to="/GetStudentInfo">GetStudentInfo</router-link> |
                <router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 to="/GetStudentInfoSingleFile">GetStudentInfoSingleFile</router-link> |
                <!--<router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 to="#" v-on:click.prevent="login" v-if="!user">StudentPortalData</router-link> |-->
                <router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 v-if="user" to="/StudentPortalDlSched">Stud DL Sched</router-link> |
                <router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 to="/StudentPortalDlSchedTS">Stud DL Sched TS</router-link> |


                <!--<a href="https://dev-236765.okta.com/home/google/0oa3mblbqpfFuNHjx357/54" target="_blank"> Calendar </a> |

    <a href="https://dev-236765.okta.com/home/google/0oa3mblbqpfFuNHjx357/50" target="_blank"> GMail </a> |

    <a href="https://classroom.google.com" target="_blank"> Google Classroom</a> |

    <a href="https://dev-236765.okta.com/home/office365/0oa164ehoco8kRUHL4x7/30781" target="_blank"> 0365 </a> |-->


                <a href="https://portal.office.com" target="_blank"> 0365 Direct</a> |
                <!--<v-list-item href="https://portal.office.com" target="_blank">Google</v-list-item> |-->


                <router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 to="/Calendar">Calendar</router-link> |
                <router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 to="/GMail">GMail</router-link> |
                <router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 to="/Classroom">Google Classroom</router-link> |
                <router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 to="/0365">0365</router-link> |
                <router-link class="pa-2" pr-2 to="/0365Direct">0365 Direct</router-link> |

                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn @click.prevent="login" color="primary" class="pa-2" v-if="!user">Login with Okta</v-btn>
                <v-btn @click.prevent="logout" color="primary" class="pa-2" v-else>Logout</v-btn>


            </v-app-bar>
            <v-card outlined class="pa-10 to accent2 lighten-4 " color="#f2f2f2" v-if="user">
                <!--<v-divider></v-divider>-->
                <v-row class="ma-2" wrap>

                    <v-col cols="12" md="6" v-if="user">

                        <!--{{user}}-->
                        {{user.preferred_username}}

                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="12" md="6" v-else>

                        USER IS NOT LOGGED IN

                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
            </v-card>

            <v-main>

                <v-container fluid>
                    <router-view />
                </v-container>

            </v-main>

        </v-app>
    </div>
</template>

 <!-- to logout call this.$auth.logout() - EWB
     below sets up Okta auth in the vue app scripts
     -->
<script>

    export default {
    name: 'app',
    data () {
      return {
        user: null
      }
    },
    async created() {
    await this.refreshUser()
    },
    watch: {
    '$route': 'onRouteChange'
    },
    methods: {
        login() {
            this.$auth.loginRedirect()
        },
        async onRouteChange() {
            // every time a route is changed refresh the user details
            await this.refreshUser()
        },
        async refreshUser() {
            // get new user details and store it to user object
            this.user = await this.$auth.getUser()
        },
        async logout() {
            //await
            await this.$auth.logout();// if I await this, it just hangs - EWB

            //await this.isAuthenticated();
            await this.refreshUser();

            this.$router.push('/');

            //alert(window.location.href);
            //window.location.href = "https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=" + window.location.href.replace("http://","");//; causes redirect notice - EWB

            //force logout of googleand redirect back to here "https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue="+window.location.pathname;;


            //if (this.$route.path !== '/') this.$router.push({
            //    path: '/' 
            //}
        }
    },
}</script>


<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin: 60px;
}

#nav {
  padding: 30px;
}

#nav a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

#nav a.router-link-exact-active {
  color: #42b983;
}
    #row {
        margin: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

I'm new to vue, and If it's not in one of those two files I have no idea where to look to figure out what I changed to break it. and Help or suggestions are appreicated.

Comment: Try removing the slash and match it to the name property: `to="0365Direct2"`

Comment: No joy, behaves exactly the same with the \ removed from the to field. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what exact behaviour you're looking for but I believe you can forgo the `router-link ` entirely and just open the link on button press. Also, I recommend posting on the VueJS forums https://forum.vuejs.org/